# Android WakeLock vs. Timer

Tags: android, timer, nfc, sensors, wakelock

I am trying to complete an android application where the phone will start off awake, attempt to gather a sample from a sensor via NFC, go to sleep, wake up, and repeat. If no sample is gathered (i.e. the sensor runs out of battery life) the application should cease data collection.

My question is, can the phone utilize its NFC capability while in sleep mode, or does the screen have to physically be awake to gather data? Also, which of these implementations if not both would be better in accomplishing the aforementioned process, and are there any examples of similar applications in existence?

Answer (score 1):

When the phone goes into sleep mode (aka, display off) NFC reader/writer abilities get turned off as well. This behavior is hard-wired in the NfcService.

Card-emulation for payment may still be active though.